# Making File and Folders Hidden in Install4j and replace installer variable action related query

Tags: replace, install4j

Is there is any way to make files/folders hidden during or install files action in install4j.
Like similar to .install4j folder in Installation folder.I am working on CentOS platform.

When install4j action replaces installer variables in files those are replaced as it is in text format,is there is any way to replace encrypted values or hide those replaced variables in shell script as it might contain sensitive information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As of install4j 8, there is no action to make files hidden
2. Call `context.registerHiddenVariable("<variable name>")` in a script to tell install4j that an installer variable contains sensitive information. Its contents will not be written to the log file.

Comment: Is it useful when replacing variables in files or scripts using replace installer variable option?

Comment: Yes, it applies to all places where a variable change or a property containing this installer variable would be logged to the log file.